# Work out the overall progress (%) of three nested for loops

Tags: c, for-loop, progress

I have three nested for loops, each of which obviously have a limit. To calculate the progress of any one of the three for loops, all that I need to do is to divide the current iteration by the total number of iterations that the loop will make. However, given that there are three different for loops, how can I work out the overall percentage complete?

```
int iLimit = 10, jLimit = 24, kLimit = 37;

for (int i = 0; i < iLimit; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < jLimit; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < kLimit; k++) {
            printf("Percentage Complete = %d", percentage);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the following code, but it reset after the completion of each loop, reaching a percentage greater than 100.

```
float percentage = ((i + 1) / (float)iLimit) * ((j + 1) / (float)jLimit) * ((k + 1) / (float)kLimit) * 100;
```

Comment: The `printf` statement is executed `iLimit * jLimit * kLimit` times, should be easy to calculate percentage from that.

Comment: I put a counter variable in the third for loop (`int k = 0`...) to denote the number of times printf was called, and then divided it by `(iLimit * jLimit * kLimit)`, but the percentage seems to fluctuate and never reach higher than 35.53%

Comment: calculate the percent done for each individual pass through each loop ( for instance, the innermost loop is 1/(10*24*37) for each pass through the loop.  similarly the middle loop is 1/(10*24) for each pass through the loop and the outer loop is 1/10 for each pass through the loop.  Then for any specific loop, the total percent done is the sum of  (i*(1/(10) + j*(1/(10*24) + k*(1/(10*24*37)) * 100.  Naturally, all numbers and math should be performed using floating point not integers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily calculate the "change in percentage per inner cycle"

```
const double percentChange = 1.0 / iLimit / jLimit / kLimit;
```

Note, this mathematically equivalent to `1/(iLimit*jLimit*kLimit)`, however if iLimit*jLimit*kLimit is sufficiently large, you'll have an overflow and unexpected behavior.  It's still possible to have an underflow with the 1.0/... approach, but its far less likely.

```
int iLimit = 10, jLimit = 24, kLimit = 37;

const double percentChange = 1.0 / iLimit / jLimit / kLimit;
double percentage = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < iLimit; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < jLimit; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < kLimit; k++) {
            percentage += percentChange;
            printf("Percentage Complete = %d\n", (int)(percentage * 100));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "warning: format '%d' expects type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'double'" (and it doesn't show a *percentage* but a *fraction*).

Comment: suggest reversing/swapping the two lines in the innermost code block as the 'current' loop is not yet completed, so should not be counted.

Comment: @user3629249 I'm assuming there is work done before the "print" statement, and that the "printf" statement isn't the work itself.  This also would mean that the final percentage should equal 100.

Comment: @Jongware I fixed the printf statement to print the integer percentage.

Answer (score 1):

If I do understand your question right, then I think the counter variables at each level (i.e. `i`, `j`, `k`) should have a different weightage in the %age formula. Let me explain what I mean: Each increment of `j` corresponds to `kLimit` iterations of the innermost loop. So, if you have only one level of nesting (say the outermost loop using `i` is not present), total number of loop iterations would be `kLimit*jLimit` and the percentage:
`percentage = (100.0 * (j*kLimit + k + 1)) / (float)(kLimit*jLimit)`

You got the idea? Its very easy to generalize this concept to the required level of nesting. I hope you can very well figure out the needed equation for your case. Anyways here is the final formula:
`percentage = 100.0 * (kLimit * (i * jLimit + j) + k + 1) / (iLimit * jLimit * kLimit)`

Answer (score 0):

The total number of loops is `iLimit * jLimit * kLimit`, and so if you have an incrementing `percentage` in the inner loop, you can just print

```
100 * percentage / (iLimit * jLimit * kLimit)
```

Since you are using `%d` to print the percentage, you can limit everything to integer calculations. (And it avoids seeing meaningless 'exact' values such as `0.011261` for the first step.)

If you want to see properly rounded values, you can also use this:

```
printf("Percentage Complete = %d%%\r", (counter*200+iLimit * jLimit * kLimit) /
  (2 * iLimit * jLimit * kLimit));
```

The `\r` at the end is a small refinement so each line will overprint the previous one.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
int iLimit = 10, jLimit = 24, kLimit = 37;
    float percentage;
    for (int i = 0; i < iLimit; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < jLimit; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < kLimit; k++) {
            percentage = ((k+1) + j * kLimit + i*jLimit*kLimit)/(float)(iLimit*jLimit*kLimit) * 100;
            printf("Percentage Complete = %f\n", percentage);
        }
    }
}
```

This solution is very simmilar to the counter incrementation solution posted here.
The advantage for this solution is that I supplied a formula for the counter which depends on the i,j,k and the limits iLimit, jLimit, kLimit:

```
counter = (k+1) + j * kLimit + i*jLimit*kLimit
```

This way, you can find out the percentage when you know i, j, k without iterating through the loops.
Thus you can possibly reduce a O(iLimit * jLimit * kLimit) problem to a O(1) problem.

Comment: code only answers are discouraged, you should explain how this code works

Comment: this will return the wrong result as (for instance) when k==0 then none of the inner loop percentage is completed, so cannot use (K+1). I.E. a percentage should not be incremented until after the loop is completed.

Comment: @user3629249 I dissagree. If the programm gets in the k loop, this means an iteration is performed (k++ will be performed).

Comment: @RyanHaining I'm sorry, I will edit my post with explanations. It's my first one on the Stackoverflow.

Answer (score -2):

Remember that percentage is parts of 100.

To get 100 you need to do e.g. `(iLimit * jLimit * kLimit) / (iLimit * jLimit * kLimit) * 100`.

Each iteration of the loop takes `1 / (iLimit * jLimit * kLimit)` parts of the whole.

To get the percentage, "simply" do e.g.

```
float percentage = ++counter / (float) (iLimit * jLimit * kLimit) * 100.0;
```

Remember to declare and initialize the `counter` variable before the loops.

Comment: If each iteration does represent `1 / (iLimit * jLimit * kLimit)`, the surely it would be `count / (iLimit * jLimit * kLimit) * 100`

Comment: this math, starting with: '(iLimit * jLimit * kLimit) / (iLimit * jLimit * kLimit) * 100' is not correct, so downvoted

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't immediately recognise that `1 / (iLimit * jLimit * kLimit)` represented 1 iteration and therefore couldn't work out the maths for the percentage behind it.

Comment: This aproach performs the complete percentage calculation on each iteration of the loop (i.e. 4 multiplications + 1 division + 1 addition). One optimized aproach is to precompute the percentage increment per iteration, so on each iteration of the loops, there is only 1 addition. See Daniel's answer

Comment: @LoPiTaL The big compilers are pretty good at common-code elimination in basic blocks these days, but yes it's a pretty easy "hand-made" optimization to move invariant expressions to outside the loops.